Combine Azure Functions ASGI App (Python v2 model) with Storage Queue Output Binding
We are developing an Azure Functions ASGI application using the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/fastapi-on-azure-functions/
We want to connect routes from the ASGI application with a storage queue by adding an output binding.
Here is what we are trying to do:
# function_app.py
import azure.functions as func
from src.main import app as fastapi

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@fastapi.post('/test')
@app.queue_output(...) # "queue_output" not offered for AsgiFunctionApp
async def receive_post_and_forward_to_queue(payload, msg: func.Out[str]):
    msg.set(payload) # put payload into storage queue

Is it correct that output bindings are not supported for ASGI applications and - if so - is there another way to connect to a storage queue by using only standard methods from Azure functions? (we don't want to use additional SDK).
One idea we came up with was to use the blueprint concept and create an additional ("standard") Azure function with an output binding and call this function from our FastAPI routes.
# blueprint.py
import azure.functions as func

bp01 = func.Blueprint()

@bp01.function_name(name="QueueOutputFunction")
@bp01.queue_output(arg_name="output", 
                  queue_name="test-queue", 
                  connection="Storage")
def send_message_to_queue(payload: str, output: func.Out[str]):
    msg.set(payload)


# function_app.py
import azure.functions as func

from blueprint import send_message_to_queue
from src.main import app as fastapi

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@fastapi.post("/test")
async def receive_post_and_forward_to_queue(payload):
    send_message_to_queue(payload)


app.register_blueprint(bp01)

With this approach we had following issues:

You can not create an Azure function without a trigger. It must have exactly one trigger.
There is no reasonable choice for a standard trigger that we could use for the blueprint function, so we tried to implement a "generic trigger". Generic triggers are not documented for Python v2 model - does anyone have a working example for this?


It looks like you need to use a trigger in Blueprint() to get the expected response. So I would suggest you to either create a queue trigger function for sending the payload from one queue to another or http trigger function to receive the payload from any endpoint or from request body in blueprint.py file instead of calling the method from function_app.py file.
I have used http trigger function and adding the payload in request body.
function_app.py-
import azure.functions as func 
from fastapi import FastAPI 
from blueprint import bp01

fast_app = FastAPI() 

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fast_app, 
                           http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

app.register_blueprint(bp01)

blueprint.py-
import azure.functions as func

bp01 = func.Blueprint()


@bp01.queue_output(arg_name="msg", 
                   queue_name="test-queue", 
                   connection="StorageConnectionString")

@bp01.route(route="send_message_to_queue", methods=["POST"]) 
def handle_http_request(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[str]):
    req_body = req.get_json()
    payload = req_body.get('message')
    if payload is None:
        return func.HttpResponse("Payload cannot be None", status_code=400)
    msg.set(payload)
    return func.HttpResponse("Message sent to queue", status_code=200)

In this way, I am able to connect to storage account.



If you are willing to send the message without using queue output then you can use the below code.
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient
from src.main import app as fastapi

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@fastapi.post("/test")
async def receive_post_and_forward_to_queue(payload: dict):
    connection_string = "StorageAccountConnectionString"
    queue_name = "test-queue"

    queue_service_client = QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    queue_client = queue_service_client.get_queue_client(queue_name)

    queue_client.send_message(payload["message"])
    return {"status": "Message sent to queue"}


Hi Afrin, how did you manage to run the "send_message_to_queue" route in parallel to your FastAPI routes?
When I run this code, every HTTP request is routed to the FastAPI app and since the "send_message_to_queue" is not handled via FastAPI, the function app returns a "404 not found".
As soon as I switch from ASGI App to "standard" FunctionApp, your code works:
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
app.register_blueprint(bp01)

@koanplaned In my case, I am using app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fast_app,http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS) not a normal funtion app. Have you made any changes to my code?

@koanplaned while executing the function, are you getting endpoint alike me?

Yes, I'm also using "AsgiFunctionApp" and I can also see both endpoints when I start the FunctionApp via Core Tools.
It shows http_app_func: [GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PATCH,PUT,OPTIONS] http://localhost:7073//{*route} handle_http_request: [POST] http://localhost:7073//send_message_to_queue
I can see two slightly different things between your and my code:


The "handle_http_request" handler is shown first in your screenshot and on my side it comes second in the list


The routes on my side are separated with to // instead of one /



@koanplaned How are you triggering localhost:7073//send_message_to_queue, using postman or browser? Please add "extensions": {     "http": {         "routePrefix": ""     }   } in host.json file

I triggered it via Postman

Have you added routePrefix in host.json? Try to invoke localhost:7073/send_message_to_queue

Yes I did add it. Here's the current host.json: {
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
},
"extensions": {
"http": {
"routePrefix": ""
}
},
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"excludedTypes": "Request",
"isEnabled": true
}
}
},
"version": "2.0"
}

can you invoke localhost:7073/send_message_to_queue?

When I invoke [POST] localhost:7073/send_message_to_queue, the services returns 404 Not found with JSON message "{"detail": "Not Found"}. This json message is typical for FastAPI when there is no route configured. So it seems every http-request is forwarded to FastAPI and the one I defined in the blueprint does not take over in that specific case.

Please share the screenshot of your folder structure and code of all the files
